# Error inflating row layout in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to implement [flowtextview](http://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/) into [bauerca / drag-sort-listview](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) but I'm getting an error inflating a row. Could you help me?

Error line is in (ResourceDragSortCursorAdapter.java (Bauerca)):

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mInflater.inflate(mLayout, parent, false);
}
```

Eclipse says:

Ecipse says "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflataing class com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView"

The row layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="67dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

     <com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView
      android:id="@+id/nuevo_ingr_row_text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
      android:id="@id/drag_handle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="67dp"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:background="@drawable/ic_move" />

<ImageView
      android:id="@id/click_remove"    
      android:layout_width="67dp"
      android:layout_height="67dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="400dip"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:background="@drawable/ic_close" />
 </com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you provide the complete stack trace please?

Comment: Do you mean all the "AndroidRuntime" error in red? If so, the error is there. Next errors are because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably fails to find your com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView class.

First check if this class is actually in that package? Did you use a library or copy this class into your own project? If you copied it, you'll need to change the package to the correct value aka point it to your own class.

Comment: I added the flowtextview class as a jar to my project. i didn't use it more because is not necessary. If I write FlowTextView. in the ResourceDragSortCursorAdapter.java it recognise the class

Comment: An easy way to check if that is the case, at least in Eclipse, is to hover over the line com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView with your ctrl (or cmd) button pressed and left-click the line. Like you can in your code with methods and classes.
If everything is correct, you should be re-directed to the correct class, altho since its a .jar you might not see the actual java code.

Answer (score 0):

You got that error just because your xml layout file is not recognise the package `com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView`

If you change it to right one then error will not be there.

Feel free to comments.

Comment: Are you sure? The class is avalaible and recognised by the class where the error is

Comment: So, what about the package ? Is the class in same package ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the FlowTextView class. The project has had quite a few bug fixes and the JAR file hasn't been updated so I would advise against using the JAR file and check the whole source out and use it as a library project.

This means you get the latest version and it will probbly solve your import issue at the same time.

IF you are not familiar with library projects in eclipse then [check this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html)